# Powershell code to extract number between two asterisks in a string

Tags: string, powershell, parsing, substring

I know this should be easy, I've Googled the h$!| out of it! But I can't figure it out. I need the number, in this case 101, that's between the ~GE* and the next * which is all embedded in a fairly gnarly string of data. A sample string of data is below:

ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*DIANER         *ZZ*88888          *200401*1305*^*00501*000044761*1*P*:~GS*HC*DIANER*88888*20200401*130536*44761*X*005010X222A1~ST*837*59892*005010X222A1~SE*50*59892~GE*101*44761~IEA*1*000044761~

Comment: You can use `$null = $string -match '~GE\*(\d+)\*'; $matches.1`. However, I would imagine you want this to work more dynamically, yes? The problem with this scenario is that there are a lot of pairs of asterisks. How do you always know which pair it will be?

Comment: [1] is that supposed to be ONE line? [2] PLEASE, wrap the sample data in code formatting so that it will be readable ... and to prevent markdown from eating some of the characters.

Comment: Sorry, Lee, newbie here. I'm learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer without knowing a bit more about the circumstances. But if one can assume that the structure of the data is that it is a set number of data points separated by asterisks, and it is always the same number of elements, then to extract the value all you would need to do is split the string on the asterisk and reference the appropriate location in the array:

```
$data = "ISA*00* 00 ZZDIANER *ZZ*88888 *200401*1305*^*00501*000044761*1*P*:~GSHCDIANER*88888*20200401*130536*44761*X*005010X222A1~ST*837*59892*005010X222A1~SE*50*59892~GE*101*44761~IEA*1*000044761~"

$data.Split("*")[24]
```

The above will return: 101

The above works if you know that the value will always be found in the exact same location in the string.

If it can move, then you could try finding it via a pattern match - ie, look for a pattern of *, three numbers, and another * (but the data might contain another segment that matches that pattern) , or if that value is always preceded by another identifiable value , you could search for that and then pull the next segment which would be the value you are looking for.

It really depends on the particulars of the dataset.

Comment: I love this approach. Actually I gutted my sample data due to PHI so my target wouldn't be 24 from the beginning; however, it would always be a set number of asterisks from a "marker". For example, I just found out that I also need to extract the value between the 2nd and 3rd asterisk after ~SE*. Could I trouble you to show me how I could use this strategy but with a starting point like ~SE*? Thank you very much!

Comment: I just made the amazing discovery that I can use negative numbers between square brackets of the Split function!! I can get exactly what I need this way. So very cool!!! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, was not monitoring because i think you had selected the other option - did you get everything worked out, or was there another question?

Comment: No problem. Yes, I'm all squared away now. Using SPLIT for lots of things too. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = 'ISA*00* 00 ZZDIANER *ZZ*88888 *200401*1305*^*00501*000044761*1*P*:~GSHCDIANER*88888*20200401*130536*44761*X*005010X222A1~ST*837*59892*005010X222A1~SE*50*59892~GE*101*44761~IEA*1*000044761~'

[regex]$r = 'GE\*.*\*44761'
$r.Matches($test).Value
```

The main caveat here is that if .Matches() returns more than one value, you'll need to tighten down the regex or iterate through the matches to find the one you actually want and you'll need to trim off the excess... hopefully some facet of this data is consistent or this will be a rather fruitless endeavor.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I wish I had asked for help sooner. I might still have some hair left. I will try it now and post again but to answer your question about multiple matches, there will always only be one occurrence of ~GE* (famous last words).

Comment: Works great! Thanks again.

Comment: I lied a little. I did have to tweak the regex since the 44761 is not a constant. But it got me on the right track.

Comment: This was a great idea but I did end up using Nim's SPLIT function. It worked well on my file for other things too. Thank you very much for your input! I learned from it.